# LSTM for time series forecasting bad performance

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, lstm

I am trying to design a neural network for time series forecasting using LSTM neurons.

I am stuck because the many different configurations that I tried so far are not performing well (actually they perform really really bad).

So I am starting to think that I'm missing something :).

This is the time series that I am using for training. I have a similar time series for testing (the training consists in 2016 data and test is 2017):
[image]

What I want is to take `T` steps of my time series and predict the following `P` steps, so I converted the problem in a multi-output regression problem in order to solve it using supervised learning: suppose I want to predict the series from time `a+1` to time `a+P`, the features of my dataset are the steps from `a-T` to `a`, (by consequence my `y`s for training are the steps from `a+1` to `a+P`)

As only preprocessing step, I applied different types of scaling (using `scikitLearn`:

```
stdscaler = StandardScaler()
minmaxScaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
robustscaler = RobustScaler()
```

Sometimes I combined these methods, but I have always got bad results in term of network performance.

After preprocessing and reshaping, I designed the following network:

```
# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(NODES_L1, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1, SEQ_LEN), stateful=True, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE))
model.add(Activation(ACTIVATION_L1))
model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT_L1))

model.add(LSTM(NODES_L2, stateful=True))
model.add(Activation(ACTIVATION_L2))
model.add(Dropout(DROPOUT_L2))

model.add(Dense(OUTPUT_TIMESTEPS, activation='linear'))
adam = Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam)

callbacks = [
    EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.00001, patience=5, verbose=0, mode='auto')
]

model.summary()

model.fit(
    trainX,
    trainY,
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=(validX, validY),
    verbose=2,
    callbacks=callbacks)
```

Two LSTM layers and one dense at the end to predict the time steps. The validation loss and the loss are descending quite well; what I see when I train the network is the following output:

```
4s - loss: 3.8233 - val_loss: 0.6118
Epoch 2/100
3s - loss: 3.4985 - val_loss: 0.6668
Epoch 3/100
3s - loss: 3.1761 - val_loss: 0.6724
Epoch 4/100
3s - loss: 2.7586 - val_loss: 0.5258
Epoch 5/100
3s - loss: 2.3404 - val_loss: 0.3424
Epoch 6/100
3s - loss: 2.0137 - val_loss: 0.2554
Epoch 7/100
3s - loss: 1.7479 - val_loss: 0.1697
Epoch 8/100
3s - loss: 1.5935 - val_loss: 0.1564
Epoch 9/100
3s - loss: 1.3824 - val_loss: 0.1206
Epoch 10/100
3s - loss: 1.2645 - val_loss: 0.0699
Epoch 11/100
3s - loss: 1.1752 - val_loss: 0.0619
Epoch 12/100
3s - loss: 1.1283 - val_loss: 0.0711
```

And so on (until early stop kills everything).

After the training step, I try to do some predictions, here the results:
[image][image]
[image]
[image]

Not even close.

I tried to find the best hyperparamters with hyperopt, here the configuration I used (maybe I am wrong on the dimension of the network):

```
fspace = {
        'SEQ_LEN': hp.choice('SEQ_LEN', range(5, 48)),
        'NODES_L1': hp.choice('NODES_L1', range(1, 80)),
        'NODES_L2': hp.choice('NODES_L2', range(1, 80)),
        'DROPOUT_L1': hp.uniform('DROPOUT_L1', 0.05, 0.8),
        'DROPOUT_L2': hp.uniform('DROPOUT_L2', 0.05, 0.8),
        'BATCH_SIZE': hp.choice('BATCH_SIZE', range(25, 150)),
        'ACTIVATION_L1': hp.choice('ACTIVATION_L1', ['relu', 'tanh']),
        'ACTIVATION_L2': hp.choice('ACTIVATION_L2', ['relu', 'tanh']),
        'EPOCHS': hp.choice('EPOCHS', range(15, 1000))
    }
```

Where `SEQ_LEN` is the number of `T` timesteps used as features.

The question is: how can I improve my process? What I am doing wrong? I double checked my code and all data seems to be loaded correctly, so I think it's a methodological problem.

Thank you for any clue ;)